# Find the set of all possible paths from the source to destination covering all edges

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding, edges

I have a directed graph. I want to find all possible paths from the source to destination covering all transitions. This is different from "all possible path covering all vertices". The graph will have exactly one start vertex and may have several end vertex. A node is an end node if it has no outgoing transition. A path in the set may have duplicate transitions but cannot have duplicate vertices. An example directed graph is attached. Vertex ***a*** (black) is the start vertex and vertex ***e*** and ***f*** are the end node (yellow). 
The solution for this graph is as below.

```
a-f
a-b-f
a-b-c-e
a-b-c-d-e
a-b-c-d-b-f
```

You can see that the last path has ***b*** two times. This is valid. i.e., a path can have the same vertex more than once. The corresponding transitions are

```
t18
t1-t7
t1-t2-t3
t1-t2-t4-t5
t1-t2-t4-t6-t7
```

You can see that no path has duplicate transitions. I need a java program to do that.
I wrote a program to solve this. But it gives me all paths without duplicate vertices. Therefore, I am missing some edges, though it covers all nodes. The code I wrote is given below

```
private Stack<Vertex> path = new Stack<Vertex>(); // the current path
private Set<Vertex> onPath = new HashSet<Vertex>(); // the set of vertices
public void AllPaths(Vertex s) {
    enumerate2(s);
}

private void enumerate(Vertex v) {
    // add node v to current path from source
    path.push(v);
    onPath.add(v);
    if (v.getOutgoings().size() == 0) {
        printPath(path);
        addToRawPaths(path);
    }

    // consider all neighbors that would continue path with repeating a node
    else {
        EList<Transition> ts = v.getOutgoings();
        for (Transition w : ts) {
            if (!onPath.contains(w.getTarget())) { // !onPath.contains(w.getTarget())
                enumerate(w.getTarget());
            }
        }
    }

    // done exploring from v, so remove from path
    path.pop();
    onPath.remove(v);
}
```

Using this, I am getting

```
a-f
a-b-f
a-b-c-e
a-b-c-d-e
```

But I need something like I described above. You can assume these api I used in this code or you can implement new. Even psudocode is fine. I need the solution to apply in a model-based testing tool to generate test cases. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are getting? Doesn't your code work? What error does it give? As it is written you are asking about help coding more than help in solving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you stop enumerating when you find a `Vertex` that's already contained in `onPath`. This shouldn't be the rule in your case. In contrast, you should stop enumerating when the pair currentVertex `v`, nextCandidateVertex `w.getTarget(`) do exist on your current path one after the other.

To achieve that, I would use a `HashSet<VertexPair>` of consecutive vertices rather than a `HashSet<Vertex>`. I guess your `Transition` objects correspond to a `VertexPair`; if this true, you may directly use `HashSet<Transition>`.

Actually, you can achieve the same functionality using your `path` stack, but looking for an existing pair may require O(n) VS amortized O(1) with the suggested approach of `HashSet<VertexPair>`.